# The song in my thought

Tags: translation

> 蘇る 思い出の歌
>   この胸に 今も優しく

1. `The song of returning thoughts` or `The song returning in [my] thoughts`?
2. Does `yasashiku` at the end imply a verb or is it a sort of continuous form, as I sometimes seem to see done with -i forms of verbs? Maybe it is from `yasashiku naru`, so both things?

Comment: 「思い出の歌が、この胸に、今も優しく、蘇る。」って言ってるのでは？

Comment: かもしれん。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 「よみがえる思い出の歌が、この胸に今も優しい。(優しく響く。)」かも・・・。By the way, 思い出 means "memories"

Comment: So should I interpret this bit as in the first comment, i.e. "A song of memories returns, tenderly even now, in my breast", or should I imply "hibiku" as in the second comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

蘇る means "come to life again". 思い出の歌 means, a song that makes you nostalgic. So in this case, the nostalgic song which was shelved in his/her mind came to life again probably because he/she heard it again.

"今も優しく" means "still tender" and この胸に roughly means "to my heart". I.e. "Still tender to my heart".

Comment: Not really.  If you actually heard the song again, you would not describe the experience as （歌が）蘇る.  If the song returned to your heart without actually hearing it, that is called 蘇る.

Comment: @非回答者: I'd disagree. 蘇る implies it occurs outside of your control. Thus it's primarily used when there is a trigger. It's of course unclear what the trigger here is, but I don't find it weird if it's him/her actually hearing the song again. He/she could be "re-experiencing" the particular instances of this song being played in the past, triggered by hearing the song again. After all it's the associated emotions that 蘇る and not the song.

Comment: So it couldn't be "the song of memories / the memory that comes back to life"? That is, the song associated to one or more memories that you are very vividly recalling (hence the feeling they are "coming back to life")?